# Read Specific Value from .txt file and storing it in a variable

Tags: c#

I am looking to read a `.txt` file in c# for a specific value then store it in a value itself example I have a text file, `example.txt`, having several lines however I am searching for a line that states `Damian:2014/12/04`then only store `2014/12/04` to a initialized value example `DateTime storedate;` Using this example I managed to read all the lines in the file and search for the specific file, however I dont know how to store it and do the trim to just capture the date and the date is interchangeable so its just the the date that follows im trying to get.

```
int counter = 0;
DateTime storedate;
string line;

StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\example.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   if (line.Contains("Damian:"))
      // Im stuck as what to do next
}
file.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(line.Contains("Damian:"))
    storedate = DateTime.Parse(line.Replace("Damian:","").Trim());
```

would be the simplest way to grab the date you're after.

Comment: This is slower, and more complicated than line.Split()

Comment: @heh, but unlike your answer it converts to a DateTime, which is what was specified in the question

Comment: Seems like you don't need the `Trim`, `DateTime.Parse` works with leading/trailing spaces

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
// Initialize outside of while loop.
DateTime storeDate = new DateTime();

if (line.StartsWith("Damian:"))
{
   storeDate = DateTime.Parse(line.Split(':')[1]);
}
```

Less code, and probably faster than replace + trim.

`line.Split(':')[0]` gets the left-side of the colon, in this case, "Damian." `line.Split(':')[1]` gets whatever is on the right-side of it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just pointing out: `StoredDate` would have to be initialized before the `while` loop, outside the `if-statement`. Also, the value returned is a `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Wouter! I'll be using that format from now on.

Comment: I'd use TryParse since it doesn't throw exceptions like Parse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to get a perfect match:

```
DateTime? storeDate = null;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\example.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var m = Regex.Match(line, @"Damian:\s*(?<storedate>[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})");
        if (m.Success)
        {
            storeDate = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["storedate"].Value);
            // break;
        }
    }
}
if (storeDate.HasValue)
    Console.WriteLine("StoreDate = " + storeDate.Value);
```

If the file is small enough to fit in memory, you can use [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and simplify the code to:

```
DateTime? storeDate = null;
var m = Regex.Match(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\example.txt"), @"Damian:\s*(?<storedate>[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})");
if (m.Success)
{
    storeDate = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["storedate"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("StoreDate = " + storeDate.Value);
}
```

Comment: How would I get it to display dd/mm/yyyy and not dd/mm/yyy:00:00:00 the time area

Comment: You can use the [`ToString(string format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) overload. Like `Console.WriteLine("StoreDate = " + storeDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));`

Comment: Ok @Wouter Huysentruit but does this actually store the date as well in that format, because Im looking to store the date (dd/mm/yyyy) in a variable

Comment: Just store it in a `DateTime` and ignore the time part wherever you use its value.

Comment: I actually cant ignore it,little history on what I am doing im creating a script to move around file to various dates folders, and when it Includes 00:00:00 I cannot create a folder

Comment: You can, the function that creates the folder just uses `mydate.Format("dd/MM/yyyy")` to determine the folder name it needs to create or look for. Don't see the problem here

Comment: one last Problem the line: 'storeDate = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["storedate"].Value);' how do I format it to be 'dd-MM-YYYY'